# Windows Task Scheduler do not open a program that is already open

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I have a task that opens a program at log on after a few minutes but I can not find a way to stop the task from activating in case the program is already open.

Also, is it possible I can put an argument or something to achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Task Scheduler, run task if task isn't running?](https://superuser.com/questions/1097766/windows-task-scheduler-run-task-if-task-isnt-running)

Comment: @harrymc that one would only work if the task is the only means of starting the program. I have a strong feeling OP wants to not start the task if the user starts the program themselves.

Comment: Chris: Is your problem as @LPChip said above, and the program can be started by other means than by the Task Scheduler?

Comment: One option is to write a bat script that checks if the process is running, then run it if not.  The bat script can be run every hour on the Task Scheduler.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script

Comment: @harrymc  yes like @ LPChip said i want the task to execute a few minutes after i log on only if i haven't already open the program my self. (about the scripts i don't know how they work or how to make them)

Comment: The example script in my above link does exactly that. @LPChip: It is after all a duplicate.

Comment: @harrymc agreed.